# How to troubleshoot disk controller on Illumos based systems?

Tags: solaris, zfs, illumos, omnios

I am using OmniOS which is based off of Illumos.

I have a ZFS pool of two SSD's that are mirrored; the pool, known as `data` is reporting its `%b` as 100; below is `iostat -xn`:

```
r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
0.0    8.0    0.0   61.5  8.7  4.5 1092.6  556.8  39 100 data
```

Unfortunately, there is not actually a lot of throughput going on; `iotop` reports about `23552` bytes a second.

I also ran `iostat -E` and it reported quite a bit of `Transport Errors`; we changed the port and they went away.

I figured there might be an issue with the drives; SMART reports no issues; I've ran multiple `smartctl -t short` and `smartctl -t long`; no issues reported.

I ran `fmadm faulty` and it reported the following:

```
--------------- ------------------------------------  -------------- ---------
TIME            EVENT-ID                              MSG-ID         SEVERITY
--------------- ------------------------------------  -------------- ---------
Jun 01 18:34:01 5fdf0c4c-5627-ccaa-d41e-fc5b2d282ab2  ZFS-8000-D3    Major     

Host        : sys1
Platform    : xxxx-xxxx       Chassis_id  : xxxxxxx
Product_sn  : 

Fault class : fault.fs.zfs.device
Affects     : zfs://pool=data/vdev=cad34c3e3be42919
                  faulted but still in service
Problem in  : zfs://pool=data/vdev=cad34c3e3be42919
                  faulted but still in service

Description : A ZFS device failed.  Refer to http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-D3
              for more information.

Response    : No automated response will occur.

Impact      : Fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised.

Action      : Run 'zpool status -x' and replace the bad device.
```

Like it suggests I ran `zpool status -x` and it reports `all pools are healthy`.

I ran some DTraces and found that all the IO activity is from `<none>` (for the file); which is metadata; so there actually isn't any file IO going on.

When I run `kstat -p zone_vfs` it reports the following:

```
zone_vfs:0:global:100ms_ops     21412
zone_vfs:0:global:10ms_ops      95554
zone_vfs:0:global:10s_ops       1639
zone_vfs:0:global:1s_ops        20752
zone_vfs:0:global:class zone_vfs
zone_vfs:0:global:crtime        0
zone_vfs:0:global:delay_cnt     0
zone_vfs:0:global:delay_time    0
zone_vfs:0:global:nread 69700628762
zone_vfs:0:global:nwritten      42450222087
zone_vfs:0:global:reads 14837387
zone_vfs:0:global:rlentime      229340224122
zone_vfs:0:global:rtime 202749379182
zone_vfs:0:global:snaptime      168018.106250637
zone_vfs:0:global:wlentime      153502283827640
zone_vfs:0:global:writes        2599025
zone_vfs:0:global:wtime 113171882481275
zone_vfs:0:global:zonename      global
```

The high amount of `1s_ops` and `10s_ops` are very concerning.

I'm thinking that it's the controller but I can't be sure; anyone have any ideas? Or where I can get more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` pool is a `lofi` encrypted ZFS container; this is the problem.

I'm able to confirm that it's a performance issue with lofi's "virtual" controller because of the following:

- lofi + zfs + encryption has a throughput of about 10-25MB/s
- lofi + zfs + no-encryption has a throughput of about 30MB/s
- No lofi with plain old ZFS has a throughput of about 250MB/s
- The `data` controller reports 100% utilization whereas the real controller has virtually none.
- Tested on multiple machines with the same setup and the results were largely identical.

The issue here is `lofi`; and not the disk controller.